# Use environment variable set by a batch script in the next batch script run

Tags: batch-file, go, environment-variables, windows-scripting

Actually i want to run 2 bat scripts , first script will set a system variable `set NEWPATH="E:/Some"` and second script will show the path of that variable: `echo %NEWPATH%`. this is not working with the same server at first time , when i restart server that will show the path otherwise it'll show nothing. so can anyone help me on that?

Comment: See the [`setx` command](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) for permanently setting environment variables in user or system context (this is the third possible way, @kostix)...

Comment: yes it'll be updated permanently but won't be available till restart the server. @as

Comment: @aschipfl, thanks! I wasn't aware of this command. The problem is that I don't know of any easy solution of replacing the environment block of the current process with the updated one. Well, except for resorting to directly calling out into Win32 API. And another obvious problem is that supposedly communicating a single key+value combo between two processes executed in a sequence *this way* is a gross overengeneering IMO:

Comment: @aschipfl since on Windows users' and system environment blocks are stored in the registry, the OP's server could just directly use a dedicated registry entry in HKCU for this purpose. I think this would still be an overengeneering but on on a lesser scale at least :-)

Comment: @shagul, by the way, are you *already* using the `setx` command in the first batch script? (That would explain that "when i restart server that will show the path otherwise it'll show nothing" passage to me--which I failed to comprehend initially).

Comment: @kostix, I agree, using `setx` and the registry for passing a value from one process to another is kind of over-engineering, I would rather go for a temporary file probably, or for the first option in your answer, if possible...

Comment: func one(){
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "bat1.bat")
    cmd.Start()
    timer := time.AfterFunc(1*time.Second, func() {
        err := cmd.Process.Kill()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err) 
        }
    })
    err := cmd.Wait()
    timer.Stop()

    // read error from here, you will notice the kill from the 
    fmt.Println(err)
    }
    
  ..same thing i did for second script in func two()

Comment: The batch file contains just a line "setx /M My_PATH "C:/path"

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully grasp your problem, but here's a couple of observations.

#### Some theory

- Environment vaiables set in a batch file (which is being executed by a shell process, `cmd.exe`)—or any other kind of process—can only be set for *that very* process.

  That is, each process has a special block with environment variables made available to it by the OS when that process is created.

  This also means that when the process which set an environment variable is finished, it's environment block is gone.
- An environment variable can be inherited by a process which was started by the process which has set that environment variable.

#### What happens in your case

What this means is that if you run two batch scripts in a sequence, this means

1. The first `cmd.exe` process is strated, the batch script it executed
   set an environment variable; then the process is gone, and its environment block is gone, too.
2. Then another `cmd.exe` is started, it inherits the environment block of your host process (written Go), but as you can see, whatever is set by a first batch script is not available.

#### What you can do about it

There are two possible ways to solve the problem:

- Make the first batch script call the second one by itself.

  In this case the second `cmd.exe` will inherit the environment variables
  set by the first script and will hence "see" them.

  Note that the Windows batch command language supports the `calls`
  command to call out to other batch scripts by their pathnames.
- Make the first script communicate the value of that variable to your host process and then arrange in the host process for the second `cmd.exe` to have the indicated variable with the indicated value in its environment.

  Say, the first script could just do something like

  ```
   echo VARNAME=value
  ```

  to have

  ```
  VARNAME=value
  ```

  printed to its stdout.

  Your Go process could parse that output, tear it apart on the `=`
  character, sanitize to not affect "interesting" variables like `PATH`,
  `USERPROFILE` etc, and then the host process could do

  ```
  env := os.Environ()
  env = env.append("VARNAME=value") // real value here
  ...
  cmd := exec.Command(`cmd.exe`, `/c`, secondScriptFilePath)
  cmd.Env = env
  ...
  cmd.Run() // or whatever
  ```

The second case can be done a bit differently: the host process
can call `os.Setenv("VARNAME=value")` to make this variable appear in its
own environment block; it then will be inherited automatically by whatever processes it starts after that.

---

Update to address the OP's comment

> …script files will be in client side so i can't add a line
>   `echo VARNAME=value` .
>   so is there any other possible way to do this?

There's another approach which might work in your case.

The idea is that `cmd.exe` is just a shell: when it's started non-interactively (that's what is done by `exec.Command("cmd.exe")`)
it reads commands from its standard input stream and executes them one by one—until the stream is closed (by the sender).

Hence you can do the following:

1. Start `cmd.exe` while connecting an instance of `io.Pipe` to its `Stdin`.
2. Open the first script *yourself* and shovel it at the running `cmd.exe` via the pipe set up on the first step.

   Don't forget to `Flush()` the pipe.

   You can use the `io.Copy()` function which sends all the data from an opened `io.Reader` to some `io.Writer`.
3. Leave the shell instance running.
4. When it's time, read the second script and shovel it at the same shell.

Since the shell is the same, the second script would run as if it were physically appended to the first one, and will see all the variables set by the first script.

Comment: thank you so much for your help but script files will be in client side so i can't add a line [echo VARNAME=value] .so is there any other possible way to do this??

Comment: @shagul, supposedly yes--consult the update to my answer.